# Cocoapods Twilio Video

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, twilio

i renamed my xcode project and delete all pods (pod deintegrate) and then i install pods again but now i get this error:

[image: use of unresolved type]

this is output from terminal after  pod install:

[image: pod install output]

My podfile:

[image: podfile]

How is it possible that my app doesnt work anymore with this new name? Can someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: I just recently ran into something similar.  After uninstalling the pod and then re installing it, the compiler was complaning about not seeing it.  But building the project the first time removed the error.  It was strange, it showed the error but allowed the project to build and then the error was gone.

Comment: Hey qetinac, did @rufus's comment help?